# External payment redirects customer via post-request to webshop-url

Tags: spartacus-storefront

In our scenario we use an external payment provider. We send a request via sap commerce to the payment provider and receive an url to which the customer is forwarded. After the shop customer has entered the payment data on this external page and the payment has been completed, the redirection to the Web shop should take place. Unfortunately, we cannot redirect the shop customer directly to a spartacus page because the request contains form data, so it is a POST request.

What is the recommended spartacus way for this usecase?

Comment: Not tried this myself but ... You do of course have SAP Commerce in the background.  Could you not have a page in Commerce that accepts the postback & then redirects?  Plus maybe have this payment process within an iframe in a Spartacus page?

Comment: yes, this is a possible way but not a good one because normally we only should have webservices in commerce and no storefront.

Comment: I'm not talking about a whole storefront, just a custom extension with a minimal/very specific web-facing app ... maybe even just the one url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We faced the same problem and solved it on the Node-server that we use for server-side rendering. We handle the post request in the express app (e.g. saving the payment token) and then redirected to another URL

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem and I plan to fix it by making a microservice that handles the POST request and redirects back to your spartacus app afterwards.

The PSP we use, requires a multitude of iframes and in the end a postback url like you have. Sad to say most PSP's don't have the right architecture to work well with SPA's